How do I add the languageCode to a new Google Places API request?
I am struggeling to send the languageCode in the API request for the Google Places API (new).
I have scoured the article Google provided for any information, but could not find any.
Here is the resource:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-details
I tried multiple ways it might work, like adding a header in the request or adding the languageCode to the link but nothing worked.
Can anyone help out?
Best regards
Aaron

Add an object called {"languageCode":"de"} in the params. This was the solution for me.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-details#languagecode - it's all there, in the documentation you linked in your question.
